# Python BigQuery client executing same query multiple times

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I came across problem, that when I query for large data (35M rows, 22GB data), the same query got executed multiple times (e.g. 400 times) in background. I understand that data is partitioned/shuffled in some way. It greatly increases query cost.

This is how I query for data:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bqclient = bigquery.Client(project)
query_job = bqclient.query(query).result()
df_result = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Where `project` and `query` are Python strings.

I am using `google-cloud-bigquery==2.30.1`.

**I am looking for any programmatic solutions to reduce query costs.** E.g. is there different class/config/object/method/library that would handle such queries in better way?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because you're calling `result()` twice, once when you run `query_job = bqclient.query(query).result()` and once when you run `df_result = query_job.to_dataframe()` (by calling `query_job` again). Not sure why it's running so many times but probably has to do with how `result()` works (https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.query should have more info)

The "basic" answer to what you want is `df_result = bqclient.query(query).to_dataframe()`. However, if you're querying a large dataset, this will likely take time. See
[Reading from BigQuery into a Pandas DataFrame and performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694593/reading-from-bigquery-into-a-pandas-dataframe-and-performance-issues) for a better way to do this.

*Side note on reducing query costs:* in case you're working in a local Python environment, you probably don't want to be processing 22GB worth of data there. If you're, say, building an ML model, you probably want to extract say 1/1000th of you data (a simple `LIMIT` in SQL won't reduce your query costs, you want to partition your table on a date column and filter on that OR create a new table with a subset of rows and query that) and work on that. Note the model on your subset of data won't be accurate, it's just to make sure your Python code works on that data. You'd then deploy your code to a cloud environment and run it on the full data. Good end-to-end example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive2/structured/solutions.